# Using jumpto and sticky_headers package causes UI issue

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a new flutter project and added the [sticky_headers](https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers) package.

Afterwards I implemented a list builder that has a ScrollController. 
I call setState 3 times at a 5 seconds interval and modify a global offset variable which will be used on the build method to jump the list to a new offset (using SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback).

The problem is that after I call the jumpto method, the headers are messed up ( if I manual scroll the headers will come back to a normal position).

**Example:**

[image: ezgif com-video-to-gif (1)]

**The code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:sticky_headers/sticky_headers.dart';

double offset = 0;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)).then((_) => setState(() {
      offset = 3000;
    })).then((_) async => await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5))).then((_) => setState(() {
      offset = 1000;
    })).then((_) async => await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5))).then((_) => setState(() {
      offset = 5000;
    }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      print(offset);
      _scrollController.jumpTo(offset);
    });
    return Scaffold(body: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),child: _buildList(context)));
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        child: ListView.builder(
            controller: _scrollController,
            itemCount: 100,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int sectionIndex) => StickyHeader(
                header: Container(
                    height: 50,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Text("$sectionIndex")),

                content: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 10,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, rowIndex) => Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Text("$sectionIndex"))))),

        onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollNotification) {
          offset = _scrollController.offset;
          print(offset);
          return true;
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: why don't you ask [here](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_sticky_headers/issues) authors of this library?

Comment: I did post an issue on their git as well.